# odd behavior with document.referrer and multiple URL's

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of html pages that include a link to an informational page. In the menu for that page, I have a link back to the referring page that uses this code:

```
<a class="nav_link" onclick="location.href = document.referrer;" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'">Return to Text</a>
```

It works as expected on the first use, but if someone moves to another page and then clicks on the link to return back, it will sometimes take them to the old referring page.  So, for example, if someone went to from page 1 to my referring page, returned via the link this anchor tag generates, and then went to page 3 and clicked on the link to the informational page, upon clicking on "Return to Text" for a second time they might go back to page 1 rather than page 3, as expected.

I'm assuming that the issue is that `document.referrer` is being stored in memory and is not being overwritten when the user clicked on the link to go to the informational page a second time.  Why is this, and is there a way for me to either make sure the memory is always cleared when they click on the link to return or create a more robust version of the `location.href = document.referrer;` onclick?

Comment: Browsers behave differently in whether they update `document.referer` when you assign to `location.href` instead of folling a link normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a "back link," you're better off with `history.go(-1)`:

```
onclick="history.go(-1);"
```

That actually emulates the back button, rather than adding a *new* entry to the history with a repeat of the previous URL.